# Looping with tFileList

Tags: talend, business-intelligence

I'm trying to loop into a directory to get images files. My Job is as following : 
[Talend TFileList Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9shG.png)

The problem is that in my oracle table, i find only one row (containing the last file in my folder).
The hierarchy of my files is as follow :

- MainRepo

  - SubRepo1

    ```
    - File1-1
    - File1-2
    - File1-3
    - File1-4
    ```
  - SubRepo2

    ```
    - File2-1
    - File2-2
    - File2-3
    - File2-4
    ```

    In my case, only File2-4 is persisted into Oracle DB.

Yours,
Amine

Comment: Can you give more detail of your job - a screen grab or more description?

Comment: Could you please show the remaining part of your job ? I see that you're using tOracleOutput as a lookup ?

Comment: Also, there is some sort of warning in your `tOracleOutput`, not sure but that might impact your requirement. Your `tMap` & `tOracleOutput` configuration as well the complete job layout would be helpful.